# GitHub pages dependencies issue

Tags: github-pages

I've uploaded a website I did locally to GH pages altogether with node modules it's dependent on. When looking at the website using GH pages url these dependencies don't load. My path looks like `user.github.io/project.github.io/node_modules/module/module.js` for example, GH doesn't see the node modules folder. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

moving the dependencies to `public` sorted it out